# Generated or had generated

Tags: past-perfect

Why is the following sentence correct: "The forum was a success as it had generated a plethora of ideas."

Why is the sentence, "The forum was a success as it generated a plethora of ideas." not correct.

Comment: The second sentence is not incorrect.

Comment: Can you please tell us why you think the second sentence is not "correct"? You can add to your question by using the [edit] link.

Comment: @AlanCarmack - Indeed. In fact, I think I prefer the second sentence over the first.